# JCL for previous month-year in dataset name

Tags: jcl

I need to run a job on the first work day of the month with accounting data for the month-end close(previous month) to be used in some year end jobs.  I would like to run the same job each month, with no operator intervention and have the closing month and year in the dataset name so it will be easily identifiable for what closing period the dataset was ceated. Currently run 8 separate jobs to accomplish this task. Please provide specific JCL samples.

Comment: Put in examples of the current jobs to allow us to see what you want to do? Are you submitting the batch jobs yourself or are they scheduled? Most scheduler have some form of variable that allow you to use arithmetic and work days to generate the dates you want

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you are running 8 separate job to accomplish this task, what does each job do?

Are you using any scheduler to run the job at a specific time?

You can use EZACFSM1 to use system symbolic paramters to add date/time information to dataset names.

http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/IEA1E241/2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this is to use the features of your job scheduler.  Having said that...

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=considerations-mvs-system-symbols) is a more recent reference for EZACFSM1.  OS/390 2.10 hasn't been current for over a decade.

However, you cannot just use this utility to create a dataset with date/time information in its name.  EZACFSM1 simply reads from SYSIN and writes to SYSOUT, interpreting the system symbols it reads.

You could use EZACFSM1 to write an [ALTER](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=commands-alter) statement for IDCAMS, renaming a statically named dataset (one without the year and month in it) to one that has those attributes.  It does require two additional steps, and a caveat.

```
//CATLG    EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
//DD01     DD  DISP=(NEW,CATLG),
//             DSN=STUFF,
//             AVGREC=U,
//             LRECL=80,
//             RECFM=FB,
//             SPACE=(80,(1000,100))
//*
//MKALTER  EXEC PGM=EZACFSM1
//SYSOUT   DD  DISP=(NEW,PASS),
//             AVGREC=U,
//             LRECL=80,
//             RECFM=FB,
//             SPACE=(80,(1000,100))
//SYSIN    DD  *
 ALTER STUFF NEWNAME(STUFF.Y&YR4&MON)
//*
//RENAME   EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSIN    DD DISP=(OLD,PASS),DSN=*.MKALTER.SYSOUT
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//*
```

The caveat has to do with job scheduling.  Let's say your job runs late on the last day of the month.  If it sits in the input queue long enough, it will run on the first day of the next month, making the ALTER incorrect.